# Email messages arrives without DKIM, and as spam, when I send from a specific network

Tags: postfix, dkim, amavis

In a specific case, when I send an e-mail message through thunderbird, the message arrives without the DKIM key and identified as spam at the source:

```
X-Virus-Scanned: amavisd-new at mailserver.example.com
X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-Spam-Score: 5.591
X-Spam-Level: *****
X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=5.591 tagged_above=1 required=4.5 tests=[ALL_TRUSTED=-1, DC_GIF_UNO_LARGO=1.323, HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_04=0.342, HTML_MESSAGE=0.001, MPART_ALT_DIFF=0.724, SB_GIF_AND_NO_URIS=2.199, TO_NO_BRKTS_HTML_IMG=2, TVD_SPACE_RATIO=0.001, URIBL_BLOCKED=0.001] autolearn=no autolearn_force=no
```

In the logs, it looks like this:

```
Sep 10 17:02:15 mailserver amavis[10085]: (10085-20) Passed SPAMMY {RelayedTaggedInternal}, ORIGINATING LOCAL [179.179.39.20]:51328 [179.179.39.20] <username@mydomain.com> -> <username@destinationdomain.com>, Queue-ID: 651981536, Message-ID: <fd322332-55e8-9e14-9e3f-271cf3e48f60@mydomain.com>, mail_id: WnptjhExD5Me, Hits: 5.591, size: 21343, queued_as: A77831540, 487 ms
```

If I send through webmail, which is on the same network as the server, and other networks, the message arrives with the DKIM key and without the spam tag in the source.

In the logs, it looks like this:

```
Sep 10 14:37:33 mailserver amavis[10085]: (10085-03) Passed CLEAN {RelayedInternal}, ORIGINATING/MYNETS LOCAL [10.99.0.10]:40774 <username@mydomain.com> -> <username@destinationdomain.com>, Queue-ID: 18EEA1251, Message-ID: <bb247980929a434354bf70020c457575@mydomain.com>, mail_id: YsTVvEBEP7SG, Hits: -0.999, size: 1212, queued_as: A31801540, dkim_new=default:mydomain.com, 516 ms
Sep 10 14:37:33 mailserver postfix/smtp[13458]: 18EEA1251: to=<username@destinationdomain.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026, delay=0.62, delays=0.09/0.01/0.01/0.51, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10027): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as A31801540)
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: is the dkim setup with host name mailserver.example.com or did you do it with just example.com? I ask because if the Return-path (real from) is mailserver.example.com then the host should be mailserver.example.com

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain a little more?

Comment: Is the DKIM set up for your root domain or for the return oath email from domain? Look at full headers of email for the return oath from. I ask because your friendly from domain might be example.com but maybe the return path is something,example.com. I was just suggesting you confirm things are lined up properly.

Comment: The Return-Path is the same in the both cases (username@mydomain.com). The diference is that the message flagged as Spam (on the sender server! why?) doesn't send the DKIM private key in the message raw.